# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax error during storing address

Tags: mysql

```
$temp_address=$_POST["address"]; 
//echo  ;  
$ids=$_POST["id"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO TestData (Id,Address, Lat_of_house, Long_of_house, Lat_of_obs, Long_of_obs, ans ) 
VALUES ($ids, $temp_address, $latHouse, $lngHouse,$latObs,$lngObs, $ans)";
```

(uptill here..code)

When I try to echo the value of **temp_address** it outputs the right value. 
When I hardcode the **Address column in the database**, it again stores the correct value. Only when i try and store the temp_address in the database (as shown above), it shows a syntax error. I am using varchar(255) as my datatype for the address column. 
The kind of address values i want to store include - "201 California Ave, Pittsburgh, PA"
and the specific error i get is :

> Error: INSERT INTO TestData (Id,Address, Lat_of_house, Long_of_house, Lat_of_obs, Long_of_obs, ans ) VALUES (54, 201 California Ave, Pittsburgh, PA, 40.503636, -80.07327099999998,40.50366484227394,-80.07328441104505, 3.4016586537572553)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'California Ave, Pittsburgh, PA, 40.503636, -80.07327099999998,40.50366484227394,' at line 1

Comment: `$temp_address` is a string? Strings need to be quoted you also are open to SQL injections with this..

Answer (score 0):

you should put string in 2 `'`, your query should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TestData (Id,Address, Lat_of_house, 
Long_of_house, Lat_of_obs, Long_of_obs, ans ) 
VALUES ($ids, '$temp_address', '$latHouse', 
'$lngHouse','$latObs','$lngObs', '$ans')";
```